# Java, get core dump

Tags: java, debugging, coredump

I would like to be able to analyze a Java core dump in the same manner that one would analyze a core dump from a process on a UNIX system.  However, I am not interested in having the information from the process, only the JVM level stack, heap, etc. The core dump would contain information on Java methods, variables, etc.

1. How can I tell the JVM to build a Java-level core dump?
2. What is a good tool to analyze said dump?

For instance, if this code was executed

```
public static void foo() {
  //trigger core dump
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
 foo();
}
```

I would get a core dump showing a stack of `main-->foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to do this kind of thing is to attach an interactive debugger to the JVM, pause it, and use the debugger to look at the stacks, etc.

Comment: Would this work when the code is running a production environment? As I understand, interactive debuggers only make sense from an IDE.

Comment: @Mike - you can attach a debugger to a JVM running on a production machine.  You just need to make sure that you start it with a JDPA agent enabled.

Comment: @StephenC +1 in case of no production env. but I doubt if this is practically possible in case of production env. Normally Production Machines are on a separate network (DMZ) firewalled from LAN as well as Ext Network, accessible only via dumb terminals, Doubt if Network Security team would be happy to approve opening up JPDA port, if yes  then its a great idea :)

Comment: @PrashantBhate - if you can login to the production machine, there is a Java debugger that you can use from the command line - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jdb.html.  If you can't even login, you don't have a chance.  If network security won't allow you the required network access to a machine to do your job, talk to management.  (In **my** experience, network security folks are not that inflexible.)

Comment: When you look at a JVM backtrace is it at all obvious what the backtrace of the actual Java app is? I imagine the JITing would make this more difficult. I'm mostly a C++'er so I don't really have any experience with this.

Comment: @JosephGarvin - I'm not talking about looking at a native backtrace from a core dump of the JVM.  (I know that's what the OP asked ... but IMO it is too hard.)  I'm talking about Thread backtraces produced by a JDPA agent (or equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

jstack <process id>

Will dump a stack trace of all of the running threads.  You will need to be the same user as the running java process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jmap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jmap.html) to generate a heap dump.

Once you have a heap dump, you can use a tool like the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to examine the dump.

And if what you're looking for is a stack trace, try something like [Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).